# Ionic polarisation: wave-vector of photon ~ 0

Tags: condensed-matter, photons, polarization

While discussing ionic polarization due to electromagnetic waves we discuss interaction of photons and ions of crystal.  Now, the next step is to take conservation of momentum under consideration.

Also, we consider that magnitude of wave- vector of photon is approximately zero.

What's the explanation for this consideration?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you discuss polarization of matter due to the propagation of electromagnetic waves you usually consider low-energy photons, meaning photons of long wavelenghts. Given that the inter-lattice spacing $a$ is a few angströms, if you consider for instance visible light of $\lambda \sim$ a few $100$ nm, you have $\lambda >> a$.

As the wavevector goes as $k = 2 \pi / \lambda$, you have a very small wavevector compared to the typical scale of your problem, you can consider it to be approximately zero.

Comment: and we consider only low-energy photons as the lattice wouldn't be able to follow high frequency photons?

Comment: The main reason is that photons of wavelength of order of a few angstroms would be so energetic that they would not propagate elastically inside of the material but rather interact with the electronic background (ionization, scattering...)